# CentOS difference between version

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, yum

In CentOS 7.3 when i check for available kernels, i receive the following:

```
[admin@CentOS73-x64 build]$ yum list --showduplicates kernel
...
Installed Packages
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-514.el7                                                                           @anaconda
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.2.2.el7                                                                       @updates
Available Packages
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.el7                                                                           base
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.1.1.el7                                                                       updates
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.2.1.el7                                                                       updates
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.2.2.el7                                                                       updates
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.5.2.el7                                                                       updates
[admin@CentOS73-x64 build]$
```

When im on CentOS 7.2 doing the same command:

```
[ilan@CentOS7286-64 ~]$ yum list --showduplicates kernel
....
Installed Packages
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-327.el7                                                                           @anaconda
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-514.16.1.el7                                                                      @updates
Available Packages
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.el7                                                                           base
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.1.1.el7                                                                       updates
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.2.1.el7                                                                       updates
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.2.2.el7                                                                       updates
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.5.2.el7                                                                       updates
[ilan@CentOS7286-64 ~]$
```

This means that 327 is not available for CentOS 7.3 ?

**Let me clarify my goal:**

This machine is going to be used as testing for different kernels, I need a machine that contains all kernels for CentOS 7.
For the moment all CentOS 7 kernels are:
3.10.0-123, 3.10.0-54.0.1, 3.10.0-229, 3.10.0-327, 3.10.0-514, 3.10.0-514, 3.10.0-693

I wish to avoid having multiple machines 7.0, 7.1, 7.2... I'd rather install machine 7.0 that run 3.10.0-123 and upgrade it include all the kernels i mentioned above.

Comment: Is there a practical use case why you wish to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at 3.10.0-327.el7, it's located in the 'Installed Packages' section. In fact, the 327 kernel was the initial kernel of the RHEL/CentOS 7.2 minor release. The initial kernel of the RHEL/CentOS 7.3 minor release was the 514 version. These kernels were available from the installation image.

So yes, 327 isn't available on the 7.3 as it wasn't on the installation image. Generally, it's nonsense to use previous kernel version on newer minor release (you'd have to have some strong reason to do that).

And the updates repository, you use, provides just few newest kernel versions.

Comment: Cant I update yum repodata to include the old kernels ? or the machine is not able to install old ones ?

Comment: @ilansch.   No, you cannot.

Comment: You can create your own local repository with the kernel (and other packages) available (but why?).

Comment: And if i use centos 7.0, How do i know what is the latest available kernel ? is it 3.10.-693? or they dont guarantee the latest kernel can run on a centos that is not the latest

Comment: @JaroslavKucera because i want 1 machine that will include all the kernels that were released for CentOS 7.. I want all the kernels for 7.0, 7.1, 7.2 in 1 machine...

Comment: RHEL packages are usable for all RHEL major version (in this case 7.x).

Comment: @JaroslavKucera.   That is only true if a package adheres to the standard Application Binary Interfaces (ABI)  See https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-abi-compatibility for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of having all the kernels for CentOS 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, etc. on one system is conceptionally interesting but not very practical in the real world.

Other things besides the kernel minor version and build numbers change in a minor release. For example, kernel headers and systemd will almost always change between minor releases.

Comment: Yes, i dont need kernel headers, i download kernel-sources and put them in /lib/modules/version.... i only download the BASE versions