# CentOS 7.0 - what kernels can i install ? yum does not show all

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, yum

I am using CentOS 7 - CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)

I want to download a newer kernels, I know the following kernels are available for CentOS7.X release:
 3.10.0-123, 3.10.0-229, 3.10.0-327, 3.10.0-514

But when i yum info i receive the following:

```
[admin@CentOS70 ~]$ yum list --showduplicates kernel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.spd.co.il
 * extras: centos.spd.co.il
 * updates: centos.spd.co.il
Installed Packages
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-123.el7                                                                           @anaconda
Available Packages
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.el7                                                                           base
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.1.1.el7                                                                       updates
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.2.1.el7                                                                       updates
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.2.2.el7                                                                       updates
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.5.2.el7                                                                       updates
[admin@CentOS70 ~]$
```

Why yum does not offer me to install  3.10.0-327 ? How can i present them all ?

My goal is to make a base machine that contains all the kernels. since CentOS 7.4 cannot install 3.10.0-123.el7, i will get the lowest version of 7 (7.0) and install all kernels on it.

When trying to add new repository i get connection reset by peer error.

```
name=CentOS-7.0 - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Comment: Find a repo that contains them, add it to your repos.

Comment: You already asked a similar question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401807/centos-difference-between-version/   Why the duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
What needs to be done is to update the repos file.
In my case, i want all the base versions, So i created a new file:

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Custom.repo
```

And pasted:

```
[CentOS-7.0-Base]
name=CentOS-7.0 - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

[CentOS-7.1-Base]
name=CentOS-7.1 - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.1.1503/os/x86_64/
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

[CentOS-7.2-Base]
name=CentOS-7.2 - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
#baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.2/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

[CentOS-7.3-Base]
name=CentOS-7.3 - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.3.1611/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

[base]
name=CentOS-7.4 - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.4.1708/os/Source/
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

So my output looks like:

```
[root@CentOS73-x64 admin]# yum list --showduplicates kernel
...
Installed Packages
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-514.el7                                                                           @anaconda
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.2.2.el7                                                                       @updates
Available Packages
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-123.el7                                                                           CentOS-7.0-Base
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-229.el7                                                                           CentOS-7.1-Base
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-327.el7                                                                           CentOS-7.2-Base
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-514.el7                                                                           CentOS-7.3-Base
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.el7                                                                           base
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.1.1.el7                                                                       updates
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.2.1.el7                                                                       updates
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.2.2.el7                                                                       updates
kernel.x86_64                                                                      3.10.0-693.5.2.el7                                                                       updates
[root@CentOS73-x64
```

Comment: Have you actually tried to install and boot off CentOS 7.4 kernel?

Comment: 7.4 no base. Only sources. And i dont install the kernel. Just want to query the repo.

Comment: Well, why did you not tell us that fact days ago!

Comment: Because i download it and do "manual" installation with my own logic. The solution was simple